# Hamachi и настройка шлюза

Tags: сеть, vpn

Есть сеть (ну для наглядности возьмём больше 16 компов) и по интренету надо подключиться, что б видеть все компы и работать, как будто они в одной сети со мной. Ставлю Hamachi на один и на другой компы- всё норм работает. Можно ли установить Hamachi на одном компе в сети (где много ещё других компов) и добавить в виртуальную сеть только этот компьютер (без установки hamachi на всех остальных) и что б те компьютеры, которые подкл через интернет видели не только компьютер с Hamachi, но и все остальные, находящиеся с тем компьютером в одной сети ?

Answer (score 1):

Там где хамачи нужно NAT, а на компах указать либо статический маршрут либо шлюз по умолчанию комп с хамачи и NATом